# Display AM IN, AM OUT, PM IN, PM OUT in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return a shift-clock style IN/OUT board from a table of logs.

The expected output is:

| ENROLLNO. | DAY | AM_IN | AM_OUT | PM_IN | PM_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8:36 | 12:06 | 1:06 | 6:36 |
| 4 | 1 | 7:36 | 12:06 | 1:09 | 7:36 |

Where:

- `AM_IN` is less than 11:29
- `AM_OUT` is BETWEEN '11:30' AND '12:30'
- `PM_IN` is BETWEEN '12:31' AND '14:00'
- `PM_OUT` is greater than '14:01'

Overall the results should be sorted by `ENROLLNO` and `DAY`

So far I have tried this query but it doesn't return the values I need:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spViewLOGCSF]
    @month nvarchar (max),
    @year nvarchar (max)
AS
    SELECT 
        t1.EnrollNo, t1.Day, 
        MIN(CONVERT(varchar(15), HoursAndMinutes, 100)) AM_IN,
        (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(varchar(15), HoursAndMinutes, 100))
         FROM tblGLog 
         WHERE Month = 'April' 
           AND HoursAndMinutes BETWEEN '11:30' AND '12:30') AM_OUT,
        (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(varchar(15), HoursAndMinutes, 100))
         FROM tblGLog 
         WHERE Month = 'April' 
           AND HoursAndMinutes BETWEEN '12:31' AND '14:00') PM_IN,
        MAX(CONVERT(varchar(15), HoursAndMinutes, 100)) PM_OUT 
    FROM
        tblGLog AS t1
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblEnroll AS t2 ON t1.EnrollNo = t2.EnrollNumber
    WHERE
        t1.Month = @month AND t1.Year = @year
    GROUP BY 
        t1.EnrollNo, t1.Day
```

The source data table:

#### Table name: `TBLLOGS`

Columns are: ENROLLNO, HOURS, DAYS, MONTHS, YEARS , DATETIME

| ENROLLNO. | HOURS | DAYS | MONTHS | YEARS | DATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:36 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 8:36:48 AM |
| 1 | 12:06 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 12:06:48 PM |
| 1 | 1:06 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 1:06:48 PM |
| 1 | 5:36 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 5:36:48 PM |
| 1 | 6:36 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 6:36:48 PM |
| 4 | 7:36 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 7:36:48 AM |
| 4 | 12:06 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 12:06:48 PM |
| 4 | 1:09 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 1:09:48 PM |
| 4 | 5:32 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 5:36:48 PM |
| 4 | 7:36 | 1 | APRIL | 2021 | 4/01/2021 7:36:48 PM |

Comment: HOURS seems like a misnomer.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the desired output. How do you determine whether an HOURS entry belongs into AM_IN or AM_OUT? Please explain this part of the input "4/01/2021 5:36=2:48 PM" it seems a misfit in the pattern of the rest of the column. Please show the output you get and explain the difference to the desired one.

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there.

Comment: Why does ENROLLNO 1 have 5 records? Why is AM OUT not 1:06 PM (considering 12:06 isn't in the AM either)?

Comment: I want to display in a row AM_IN, AM_OUT, PM_IN, PM_OUT
where
AM_IN is less than 11:29, AM_OUT is  BETWEEN '11:30' AND '12:30', PM_IN is BETWEEN '12:31' AND '14:00' and PM_OUT is greater than 14:01

and sort it by enroll id & day.

Comment: SQL Server != SQLite please correct your taga.

Comment: I am not commenting on the wrong tag (code looks like tsql) so I only want to point you to [tsql reference - using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15). Just to elaborate a bit: Add a column to your subquery where you add what type it is (AM_IN, AM_OUT, PM_IN, PM_OUT) and then pivot the data

Comment: I'm sorry its.. SQL SERVER

Comment: It's my bad. I edited the tags already

Comment: Kindly help.. Those master on SQL query.
Really much appreciated your kindness

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the good attitude to comments. But you should definitely provide a minimal reproducible example so we could check how it works. I'm reviewing your question and it's not clear to me: why don't ask for AM_IN only? Other columns are similar, and if not, it could be split into multiple questions

Comment: I see what you want, to clarify you should include data that spans multiple days and show the results of your attempted query so we can have a specific discussion about where you are wrong.

Comment: Some data type information would be helpful, the table create script would help

Comment: Why did you delete this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295515/how-can-i-get-all-selected-data-from-a-foreach-and-loop-it-inside-while-do-whi

Answer (score 3):

> Your first issue is that your SP is targeting a different schema to the one you have posted, it is querying tables `tblGLog` and `tblEnroll`
>
> > For the purposes of this response we will disregard the information provided in the SP script and instead will answer in terms of the posted example data!

You should not use CHAR literals to store your time components, the only columns we *need* from your example dataset are `ENROLLNO` and `DATETIME`, the Day can easily be inferred.

- `Month` and `Year` *can* help optimise indexes for some types of execution plans, however your SP is not filtering on `Day` so you will get more value by storing a `DATE` typed column for grouping and a `TIME` typed column for the filtering.

The following solution uses a *CTE* to transform the dataset, this is not 100% necessary but it illustrates the concrete columns that are required for this type of query. You could optimise your schema by including the additional columns from this *CTE* into your `TBLLOGS` schema and setting the values appropriately either as default values, or via triggers or in your `INSERT` commands.

`CROSS APPLY` is used to transform the query to apply the specifically requested column expressions, however these columns are not candidates for modifications to the original schema.

***NOTE:** The time boundary conditions have been closed so that logs at precisely `11:29` and `14:01` are included.*

```
WITH TimePeriodData as
(
  SELECT ENROLLNO, [DATETIME], DAYS, HOURS
       , CAST([DATETIME] AS Date) AS [Date]
       , CAST([DATETIME] AS TIME) AS [TIME]
  FROM TBLLOGS
)
SELECT g.ENROLLNO, g.[DATE], g.[DAYS]
     , MIN(x.AM_IN) AS AM_IN
     , MAX(x.AM_OUT) AS AM_OUT  
     , MIN(x.PM_IN) AS PM_IN
     , MAX(x.PM_OUT) AS PM_OUT  
FROM TimePeriodData g
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN [TIME] < '11:30' THEN [HOURS] END AS AM_IN
                  , CASE WHEN [TIME] BETWEEN '11:30' AND '12:30' THEN [HOURS] END AS AM_OUT
                  , CASE WHEN [TIME] BETWEEN '12:31' AND '14:00' THEN [HOURS] END AS PM_IN
                  , CASE WHEN [TIME] > '14:00' THEN [HOURS] END AS PM_OUT
             ) as x
GROUP BY g.ENROLLNO, g.[Date], g.[DAYS];
```

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0073d1/1

---

Your requirement seems incredibly specific, it would be simpler logic to specify the *midday break* time as `12:30`, then we only have a single conversion per-row. If this value is a *constant* then it is a candidate for inclusion in the data schema.

> This next query deliberately **DOES NOT *format*** the output for the `DAYS` and `HOURS` columns as requested, instead the SQL query returns the exact data type so that you can easily extend this query to other situations. Formatting the specific output should be handled in the representation layer

```
WITH TimePeriodData as
(
  SELECT ENROLLNO, [DATETIME], DAYS, HOURS
       , CAST([DATETIME] AS Date) AS [Date]
       , CAST([DATETIME] AS TIME) AS [TIME]
       , CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [DATETIME]) >=14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IS_PM] 
  FROM TBLLOGS
)
SELECT g.ENROLLNO, g.[DATE]
     , MIN(x.AM) AS AM_IN
     , MAX(x.AM) AS AM_OUT  
     , MIN(x.PM) AS PM_IN
     , MAX(x.PM) AS PM_OUT  
FROM TimePeriodData g
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN [IS_PM] = 0 THEN [TIME] END AS AM
                  , CASE WHEN [IS_PM] = 1 THEN [TIME] END AS PM
             ) as x
GROUP BY g.ENROLLNO, g.[Date], g.[DAYS];
```

This will return: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0073d1/10

| ENROLLNO | DATE | AM_IN | AM_OUT | PM_IN | PM_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | 08:36:48 | 12:06:48 | 13:06:48 | 18:36:48 |
| 4 | 2021-04-01 | 07:36:48 | 12:06:48 | 13:09:48 | 19:36:48 |

---

The following fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b09ee3/2 demonstrates how the query could be simplfied:

```
SELECT g.ENROLLNO, g.[DATE]
     , MIN(x.AM) AS AM_IN
     , MAX(x.AM) AS AM_OUT  
     , MIN(x.PM) AS PM_IN
     , MAX(x.PM) AS PM_OUT  
FROM TBLLOGS g
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN [IS_PM] = 0 THEN [TIME] END AS AM
                  , CASE WHEN [IS_PM] = 1 THEN [TIME] END AS PM
             ) as x
GROUP BY g.ENROLLNO, g.[Date];
```

> There is no example here of how to apply this to the original SP because the exact table schema is not provided, no explanation for the un-used `LEFT JOIN` reference in that SP and the Hardcoded `'April'` filtering ignored the input parameters... there is just too much mess there that I choose not to be involved with ;)

Comment: I guess the 'April' thing is that just in April they have a break, but that is just business logic that could be left away the question and answers... Plus lefting it out makes the answer simpler and more helpful to others with similar problems

Comment: @Cleptus `'April'` is simply a clear cut'n'paste error, you can't have a month parameter _and_ hardcode april... if they ONLY get a break in April, as strange as that is, you still wouldn't hardcode the month in that sub-query, that value would also be parameterised or looked up from some configuration table. Its an indication that OP is hacking this together from a few different sources, even the Schema table and field names do not match up to the example.

Comment: @Chris Schaller.. Thank you very much, you are my master now. What a great explaination, I learn a lot. God bless you.. master.

Comment: @MackyCute no worries, please mark as answer if it has helped :)